# Different behaviour in redactors regarding code .open .close files with Python

Tags: python

So, when I try to execute the following code, the behaviour of two IDE's are different.

In PyCharm the code is executing and creates a file with an input inside.

```
todos = []
todo = input("Enter a todo: ") + "\n"
todos.append(todo)
file = open('todos.txt', 'w')
file.writelines(todos)
```

But in Thonny IDE the code is executing without any errors:

```
todos = []
todo = input("Enter a todo: ") + "\n"
todos.append(todo)
file = open('todos.txt', 'w')
file.writelines(todos)
```

The file is still created, but the input is not inside, till I put a new following command:

```
file.close()
```

Why do they behave different? Is it not dependant of interpreter than of IDE's?

Comment: the executable path is probably in different places.  You can ensure both are the same by using the `full path and file name`.

Answer (score 0):

No matter the IDE if you use `open` the responsibility to `close` the file is on you and you shouldn't rely on any IDE behaviour for that.
To be safe you should use context managers `with open` syntax in order to shift the responsibility for closing the file to the interpreter.

Here's a deeper explanation:
https://realpython.com/python-with-statement/#the-with-statement-approach